# Django - It is possible to use Haystack with custom SQL directly

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm in the process of choosing a Framework for a new project. I have basically the database schema developed(I have this schema running in other PHP webapps already).

In this project I will need to basically search the database schema with Solr. The database schema is a little bit complex to define models in Django, so I think the only option I have is to execute SQL directly... my doubt is about Haystack/Solr... It is possible to query Haystack/Solr when I have no Django Models defined?

PS: I'm new to Django, I have never userd Haystack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haystack is pretty tightly coupled to the Django ORM. If you're not using Django models, I don't think Haystack is suitable. I've only used Haystack briefly, so I might wrong.

From the [Haystack docs](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/faq.html#when-should-i-not-be-using-haystack):

> **When should I not be using Haystack?**
>   Non-Model-based data. If you just want to index random data (flat files, alternate sources, etc.), Haystack isn’t a good solution. Haystack is very Model-based and doesn’t work well outside of that use case.

Comment: If you don't have models, you can just query Solr directly.

Answer (score -1):

I never used haystack, but you can always perform raw sql queries.

Have a look on documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: The question was about haystack with raw SQL queries and not just raw sql queries in Django